Can a shower vent tie in to the main vent stack below the flood level of a toilet above?
I am adding a shower to my bathroom, and was planning on tying the vent into the 3" line that vents the wall-hung toilet on the floor above. Does this meet code (TBH, I'm not sure what specific code applies in my area, but if it helps this is in Marin County, just north of San Francisco), or do I need to tie in somewhere above the rim of the toilet?
The pipe coming down at a 45 degree angle is the waste line for the toilet, and the part that goes up continues out through the roof. There's also a shower and powder room sink and toilet that tie into that 3" pipe above the ceiling of the upper floor. The red plastic bag is where I was planning on connecting the shower vent. I got creative with the framing to avoid having to deal with routing the 3" pipe through the existing top and bottom plates.

